# Parametrized queries runs only in power query successful and not in DAX

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am using a SQL Server Database via Direct Query.
There is a table containing

- Country
- Allegation
- Serial numbers (whole number; no dedicated SN ranges)

I added all three as slicer to the repoert.

Now my challenge is that the user have to select a serial number and defined amount of serial number items before and after have to be shown.
My problem is now that when a SN is selected the only the corresponding country and allegation is shown.
Now I added three parameters to my report and changed my queries that the parameters are reflected. In the query view everything works perfect. But as I switched back to the report i get following error message:

[image]

That looked crazy to me and I connected my report to DAX-Studio and figured out when the transfered M-parameters are commented out the DAX query runs successful.
Is there a possibility that these parameters are not transfered to DAX our is there another solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a recommendation for you; but I am not sure It will solve your problem. Let's start:

Screen_01

Select your parameter on the Queries Pane

[image: Parameter]

Screen_02

Go to properties on the Query Tab.

[image: ssss222]

Screen_03

Ensure that Enable load to report box is unchecked. Click Ok. Then go to your report and test it.

[image: dfsfffffff]